# IntelliJ doesn't recognize flutter plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

I wanted to try out flutter with IntelliJ, so I followed the order of https://flutter.io/setup-macos/ and everything worked out. But today, out of nowhere, it doesn't work anymore. I can run my code, but reload and hot reload is disabled. So I'd have to close and restart everything, every time, I'd like to see a change. "flutter doctor" tells me:

```
IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2017.2.5)
✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
• Dart plugin version 172.4155.35
• For information about installing plugins, see
  https://flutter.io/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins
```

But I looked it up, and flutter clearly was installed. I honestly sit here for 5 hours now, trying to figure it out, but I just can't find the problem. I deleted and reinstalled Flutter, Dart and IntelliJ like 4 times now, but it didn't work either.

Flutter in generall works, at least I can run the app in the terminal, so the problem got to be with IntelliJ. I also deleted the following folders:

```
macOS
~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdeaXX
~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdeaXX
~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdeaXX
~/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdeaXX
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do now?

Comment: Hi Günter, sorry but I'm fairly new and I don't exactly get what you mean with that. In the terminal they say that they don't have the command "switch" and when I google it I get GitHub examples for flutter switches.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `flutter channel master` might be worth a try.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, now everything works fine! Out of interest, what was wrong before? Because this problem occurred just from one day to the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was reported several times recently. `master` is the development branch with some newer code. <strike>`alpha`</strike> `dev` (default) is the recommended channel, but there are currently issues with `dev` which are already fixed in `master`. `dev` will be updated soon and it's recommended to switch back to `dev` when the fixes have landed.

```
flutter channel master
```

to switch back later

<strike>flutter channel alpha</strike>

```
flutter channel dev
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is still looking for an answer for this... Jetbrains has changed the plugins directory since the 2020.x versions (2019 - 2020)

Windows:
from: %HOMEPATH%\.\config\plugins
to: %APPDATA%\JetBrains\\plugins

MacOS:
from: ~/Library/Application Support/
to: ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains//plugins

Linux:
from: ~/./config/plugins
to: ~/.local/share/JetBrains/

To fix the problem before a flutter update, I just created a symbolic link of my plugins directory (I use mac):

```
ln -s /Users/xxx/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/plugins /Users/xxx/Library/Application\ Support/IntelliJIdea2020.1
```

That did the trick for me! I hope it helps others as well :)

Cheers.